# Android targetSdkVersion=28 and <queries> tag in AndroidManifest.xml

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-11

I have a library project with targetSdkVersion=30. To support Android-11 package visibility, it includes the  tag in AndroidManifests.xml.

Now the client project, which uses the above library project, has targetSdkVersion=28 set. This gives a compile error "unsupported  for API 28" error.

How can I proceed with fixing this problem given that the client cannot update it's targetSdkVersion to any higher than 28.

Answer (score 0):

The client should update `compileSdkVersion`. The target can stay 28. Also consider setting in your library `minCompileSdk` to 30 which will give your library users a clear hint that they should bump compile SDK version.